# setsimplecolumn doesn't position the text to the given coordinates in PDF using itextsharp 5 in C#

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext

I am new to iTextShap and I am trying to add two text columns using `SetSimpleColumn` and somehow the second column is not positioning to the given x-coordinate. I have already gone through a lot of content available on the internet and the iTextSharp documentation for the version(5.5.13.2), that I am using is not having much.

Below is the code that I have written, is there anything that I am missing? Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

```c#
Font f = new Font(baseFont, 8);

ColumnText ct2 = new ColumnText(writer.DirectContent);
ct2.SetSimpleColumn(29f, 587f, 220f, 100f, 11f, 0);
ct2.AddText(new Paragraph("PATIENT'S NAME:", f));
ct2.AddText(Chunk.NEWLINE);
ct2.AddText(new Paragraph("Street Address:", f));
ct2.AddText(Chunk.NEWLINE);
ct2.AddText(new Paragraph("Address 2:", f));
ct2.AddText(Chunk.NEWLINE);
ct2.AddText(new Paragraph("City, State:", f));
ct2.AddText(Chunk.NEWLINE);
ct2.AddText(new Paragraph("Zip Code:", f));
ct2.AddText(Chunk.NEWLINE);
ct2.AddText(new Paragraph("Telephone:", f));
ct2.Go();

ColumnText ct3 = new ColumnText(writer.DirectContent);
ct3.SetSimpleColumn(455.5f, 587f, 220f, 100f, 11f, 2);
ct3.AddText(new Paragraph("PRACTICE:", f) { Alignment = 0});
ct3.AddText(Chunk.NEWLINE);
ct3.AddText(new Paragraph("Street Address:", f));
ct3.AddText(Chunk.NEWLINE);
ct3.AddText(new Paragraph("Address 2:", f));
ct3.AddText(Chunk.NEWLINE);
ct3.AddText(new Paragraph("City, State:", f));
ct3.AddText(Chunk.NEWLINE);
ct3.AddText(new Paragraph("Zip Code:", f));
ct3.AddText(Chunk.NEWLINE);
ct3.AddText(new Paragraph("Telephone:", f));
ct3.AddText(Chunk.NEWLINE);
ct3.AddText(new Paragraph("Fax:", f));
ct3.Go();
```

Comment: *"somehow the second column is not positioning to the given x-coordinate"* - what do you mean exactly? `ct2` should be positioned starting at `x=29` and `ct3` at `x=220`. Does that not happen?

Comment: x=455.5 at ct3 is not happing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there is a misunderstanding concerning the arguments of the `SetSimpleColumn` method, you appear to assume that the first four arguments are `x, y, width, height`. Actually, though, they are `x₁, y₁, x₂, y₂`. Thus, when you do

```c#
ct3.SetSimpleColumn(455.5f, 587f, 220f, 100f, 11f, 2);
```

you make the column start at `x=220` and end at `x=455.5`.

What you want, more likely is

```c#
ct3.SetSimpleColumn(455.5f, 587f, 455.5f + 220f, 587f + 100f, 11f, 2);
```

Comment: thank for your help! Yes there was a misunderstanding regarding the arguments, my problem has been solved now.